# Python beautifulsoup performance, IDE, poolsize, multiprocessing requests.get for web-crawler

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, ide, multiprocessing, python-requests

Fine fellows of stack overflow!

New at python(second day), Beautiful Soup and sadly, in a bit of hurry.

I've built a crawler that take street names from a file into a search engine(merinfo_url). Those companies under right conditions get further scraped then exported.

I'm in a "hurry" because, despite a complete debug mess of a code everything is working! I'm itching to begin a long debug test on a remote computer today. I stopped at 5000 hits.

But performance is slow. **I understand I could change the parser to lxml, and open my local file only once.**

I hope to implement that today.

**Multiprocessing** however confuses me. What's my best option, **a pool or open several connections?** Am I using two terms for the same call?

**How large of a pool?** Two per thread seems to be frequent advise but I've seen a hundred on a local machine. Any general rule?

If I change nothing in my current code, w**here do I implement the pool** and how do you **do it generally for the requests object**?

Finally; in terms of performance, on the top of your heads, good performing IDE to debug a crawler running on a local machine?

Many thanks for any feedback offered!

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import json
import requests
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from sys import exit
from multiprocessing import Pool


def main():
  if __debug__:
    print ("[debug] Instaellningar:")
    print ("[debug]    Antal anstaellda: "+(antal_anstaellda))
    print ("[debug]    Omsaettning: "+(omsaettning))

  with open(save_file, 'wb') as filedescriptor:
    filedescriptor.write('companyName,companySSN,companyAddressNo,companyZipCity,phoneNumber,phoneProvider,phoneNumberType\n')

  lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(streetname_datfile)]
  for adresssokparameter in lines:

    searchparams = { 'emp': antal_anstaellda, 'rev': omsaettning, 'd': 'c', 'who': '', 'where': adresssokparameter, 'bf': '1' }
    sokparametrar = urllib.urlencode(searchparams)


     merinfo_url = merinfobaseurl+searchurl+sokparametrar

    if __debug__:
      print ("[debug] Antal requests gjorda till merinfo.se: "+str(numberOfRequestsCounter))
    crawla_merinfo(merinfo_url)

      # Crawler
    def crawla_merinfo(url):

  if __debug__:
    print ("[debug] crawl url: "+url)
  global numberOfRequestsCounter
  numberOfRequestsCounter += 1
  merinfosearchresponse = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
  if merinfosearchresponse.status_code == 429:
    print ("[!] For manga sokningar, avslutar")
    exit(1)
  merinfosoup = BeautifulSoup(merinfosearchresponse.content, 'html.parser')
  notfound = merinfosoup.find(string=merinfo404text)
  if notfound == u"Din sokning gav tyvaerr ingen traeff. Prova att formulera om din sokning.":
    if __debug__:
      print ("[debug] [!] " + merinfo404text)
    return
  for merinfocompanycontent in merinfosoup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'result-company'}):
    phonelink = merinfocompanycontent.find('a', attrs={'class': 'phone'})
    if phonelink == None:
      # No numbers, do nothing
      if __debug__:
        print ("[!] Inget telefonnummer for foretaget")
      return
    else:
      companywithphonenolink = merinfobaseurl+phonelink['href']
      thiscompanyphonenodict = crawla_merinfo_telefonnummer(companywithphonenolink)
      companyName = merinfocompanycontent.find('h2', attrs={'class': 'name'}).find('a').string
      companySSN = merinfocompanycontent.find('p', attrs={'class': 'ssn'}).string
      companyAddress = merinfocompanycontent.find('p', attrs={'class': 'address'}).text
      splitAddress = companyAddress.splitlines()
      addressStreetNo = splitAddress[0]
      addressZipCity = splitAddress[1]
      addressStreetNo.encode('utf-8')
      addressZipCity.encode('utf-8')

      if __debug__:
        print ("[debug] [*] Foretaget '"+companyName.encode('utf-8')+("' har telefonnummer..."))
      for companyPhoneNumber in thiscompanyphonenodict.iterkeys():
        companyRow = companyName+","+companySSN+","+addressStreetNo+","+addressZipCity+","+thiscompanyphonenodict[companyPhoneNumber]
        if __debug__:
          print ("[debug] ::: "+thiscompanyphonenodict[companyPhoneNumber])
        with open(save_file, 'a') as filedescriptor:
          filedescriptor.write(companyRow.encode('utf-8')+'\n')
  return

  #telephone crawl function
  def crawla_merinfo_telefonnummer(url):
  global numberOfRequestsCounter
  numberOfRequestsCounter += 1
  if __debug__:
    print ("[debug] crawl telephone url: "+url)
  phonenoDict = {}
  s = requests.session()
  merinfophonenoresponse = s.get(url, timeout=60)
  merinfophonenosoup = BeautifulSoup(merinfophonenoresponse.content, 'html.parser')
  merinfotokeninfo = merinfophonenosoup.find('meta', attrs={'name': '_token'})
  headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Host': 'www.merinfo.se',
    'Referer': url
  }
  headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = merinfotokeninfo['content']
  headers['Cookie'] = 'merinfo_session='+s.cookies['merinfo_session']+';'

  merinfophonetable = merinfophonenosoup.find('table', id='phonetable')
  i = 0
  for merinfophonenoentry in merinfophonetable.find_all('tr', id=True):
    i += 1
    phoneNumberID = merinfophonenoentry['id']
    phoneNumberPhoneNo = merinfophonenoentry['number']

    for phoneNumberColumn in merinfophonenoentry.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'col-xs-2'}):
      phoneNumberType = phoneNumberColumn.next_element.string.replace(",",";")
      phoneNumberType = phoneNumberType.rstrip('\n').lstrip('\n')

    payload = {
      'id': phoneNumberID,
      'phonenumber': phoneNumberPhoneNo
    }
    r = s.post(ajaxurl, data=payload, headers=headers)
    numberOfRequestsCounter += 1
    if r.status_code != 200:
     print ("[!] Error, response not HTTP 200 while querying AJAX carrier info.")
     exit(1)
    else:
      carrierResponseDict = json.loads(r.text)
      # print carrierResponseDict['operator']
      phoneNoString = phoneNumberPhoneNo+','+carrierResponseDict['operator']+','+phoneNumberType
      phonenoDict['companyPhoneNo'+str(i)] = phoneNoString
  return phonenoDict

# Start main program
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start to use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

[One of the main advantages](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) about Scrapy: requests are scheduled and processed asynchronously.

This means that Scrapy doesn’t need to wait for a request to be finished and processed, it can send another request or do other things in the meantime. This also means that other requests can keep going even if some request fails or an error happens while handling it.

Comment: Not a solution for multiprocessing requests for my code but I think you're right. I've started to build it in Scrapy, however, I still want to fully test this one and make it better.

Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Let me a [quote from Dimitrios Kouzis-Loukas's book Learning Scrapy](https://books.google.ru/books?id=EF8dDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=Dimitrios%20Kouzis-Loukas%20Learning%20Scrapy%20Preface&pg=PR7#v=onepage&q=Dimitrios%20Kouzis-Loukas%20Learning%20Scrapy%20Preface&f=false). May be you will find something close to your case )